# change UIImagePicker aspect ratio

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So im trying to make a custom camera within my iOS app.

I want to make the camera full screen like snapchats.

But i cant find anywhere that will help me change the aspect ratio from 4:3 (default) to 16:9 (iPhone 5 & 5s, 4" screens).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: AFAIK you would have to cut off parts. I would guess Aspect Fill is the right choice

Comment: cutting off parts is fine, its just that i dont know how to calculate which parts to cut off?

Comment: @Andyy any chance you found a solution?

Answer (score 4):

A little shameless self promotion here, but I have a camera project that does everything you'd like to do, plus you could customize it further for your project.  [GitHub](https://github.com/LoganWright/SimpleCam)

It does all the cutting / sizing / aspect ratios for you, while still being fullscreen on all devices.

Otherwise, There's many other options on github / cocoacontrols / elsewhere if you don't like it.  You could also make your own by checking out `AVFoundation`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the UIImagePickerController's cameraViewTransform:

```
CGSize screenBounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;

CGFloat cameraAspectRatio = 4.0f/3.0f;

CGFloat camViewHeight = screenBounds.width * cameraAspectRatio;
CGFloat scale = screenBounds.height / camViewHeight;

pickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, (screenBounds.height - camViewHeight) / 2.0);
pickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(pickerController.cameraViewTransform, scale, scale);
```

Comment: iOS 10 seems to ignore this code snippet, I had it working on iOS 9 but since the upgrade it broke and the picker shows 4:3 ratio in camera view