# How to make UIImagePickerController crop 16:9 ratio

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, ios-camera

Hi I am currently working with UIImagePickerController and it is cropping images squared by default. Is there a way that I can make it crop at a 16:9 aspect ratio? I have searched online but haven't found much results.

Comment: Please look this one https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change UIImagePicker aspect ratio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592903/change-uiimagepicker-aspect-ratio)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905156/how-to-convert-objective-c-tocropviewcontroller-delegate-method-in-swift/36905543#36905543

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIImage: Resize, then Crop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603907/uiimage-resize-then-crop)

Comment: @BhupatBheda absolute fine controller thank you three thousand times :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one [GithubLink](https://github.com/budidino/ShittyImageCrop)

```
let cropVC = ShittyImageCropVC(frame: (self.navigationController?.view.frame)!, image: imageToCrop, aspectWidth: 16, aspectHeight: 9)
self.navigationController?.present(cropVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```